# buscar una palabra en un archivo txt

Tags: java

Tengo un programa que pide al usuario un nombre para buscar sus datos en un fichero.

**El fichero contiene lo siguiente:**

```
Persona: Adrian

Apellido: Rodriguez

Edad: 19

Persona: Alejandro

Apellido: Grande

Edad: 28

Persona: Mikel

Apellido: Aparicio

Edad: 21

Persona: Rodrigo

Apellido: Novoa

Edad: 21

Persona: Asier

Apellido: Urangan

Edad: 22
```

**Y el código es el siguiente:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ficheero4 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File fichero = new File ("C:\\Users\\adminportatil\\eclipse-workspace\\ADInicio\\Ficheros\\datos.txt");

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String respuesta;

    try {
        do {
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fichero));
            System.out.println("Introduco un nombre que quieras buscar: ");
            respuesta="Persona: "+sc.nextLine();

            String linea="";
            while ((linea= br.readLine())!=null) {

                if(linea.equalsIgnoreCase(respuesta)) {
                    System.out.println(linea);

                    for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
                        System.out.println(br.readLine());
                    }   
                    break;

                }else {
                    System.out.println("El nombre introducido no existe.");

                    break;
                }

            }

            do {
                System.out.println("¿Quieres introducir otro nombre?");
                respuesta=sc.nextLine();

            }while(respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("si")==false&&respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("no")==false);


        }while(respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("si"));
    } catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.println("Error");
    }

}
}
```

El caso es que la primera vuelta linea=br.readline() recoge bien la información pero la segunda vez no y me gustaría saber porque y como solucionarlo.
Gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: Cuidado porque estás llamando a br.readLine en dos sitios distintos: uno en el  while ((linea= br.readLine())!=null) y otro dentro del for(int i=0;i<2;i++) y eso va a hacer que, quizás, no lea el fichero como esperas

Comment: E intentado lo siguiente:
    
String linea="";
    while (linea!=null) {
     linea= br.readLine();
     if(linea.equalsIgnoreCase(respuesta)) {
      System.out.println(linea);


Pero sigue fallando en la segunda vuelta.

Comment: Fíjate que tanto si la primera línea coincide con el nombre introducido como si no, se está saliendo del bucle y no lee nada más ya que tienes dos break's: uno en el if y otro en el else que hacen que salgan y pasen al siguiente while

Comment: Saludos @HelloThere, tal vez quieras editar el título de tu pregunta: este debería consistir en una pregunta concreta o una indicación de lo que quieres hacer, como "Leer datos de archivo de texto linea por linea"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en la sentencia `else` que le haces un `break` al proceso y paras la lectura del fichero dando opción a que solo salga el dato de la primera persona.

Quita el `break;` o incluso el `else`.

```
try {
    do {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fichero));
        System.out.println("Introduco un nombre que quieras buscar: ");
        respuesta="Persona: "+sc.nextLine();

        String linea="";
        boolean encontrado = false;
        while ((linea= br.readLine())!=null) {

            if(linea.equalsIgnoreCase(respuesta)) {
                System.out.println(linea);

                for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
                    System.out.println(br.readLine());
                }   
                encontrado = true;
                break;

            }

        }

        if(!encontrado) System.out.println("El usuario no existe");

            System.out.println("¿Quieres introducir otro nombre?");
            respuesta=sc.nextLine();



    }while(respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("si"));
} catch (IOException e) {

    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

Además el `br` te coge las líneas vaciás entre datos y no muestra los adtos bien. Cambialo a algo así:

```
Persona: Adrian
Apellido: Rodriguez
Edad: 19

Persona: Alejandro
Apellido: Grande
Edad: 28

Persona: Mikel
Apellido: Aparicio
Edad: 21

Persona: Rodrigo
Apellido: Novoa
Edad: 21

Persona: Asier
Apellido: Urangan
Edad: 22
```